# send and receive message in messenger software like WhatsApp

Tags: android

In messaging applications like WhatsApp or Telegram, how to send and receive messages.
Does the software check the server every few seconds once?
I've made a program for sending and receiving messages that the software checks the server every few seconds and if that message is new, it will display that message to the user.
Is my way of working correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase real-time database.

Reference: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase--cms-27397

There is also a possibility of using Firebase messaging directly but it is more involved.

---

For your question about how do whatsApp and other messaging apps work, they basically rely on sending notifications to the device when a message is received.

https://medium.com/@cdmunoz/working-easily-with-fcm-push-notifications-in-android-e1804c80f74

User authentication, identification and determining which users to target for a notification are other constraints. Libraries such as those provided by [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) can manage a lot of these details for you.